# Sending post request to nodejs using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, node.js, ajax, post

I am trying to send post request to nodejs server, But i have been getting an error.

I have this code in my .js file

> var data = {
>        firstName: "ABC",
>        lastName: "ABC" }
>
> var jax = $.post('/update', { data: data });

In nodejs server, i have this code

```
app.post('/update', function(req, res){
    console.log('body: ' + JSON.stringify(req.body));

    var obj = req.body.data;
    console.log("obj is " + JSON.stringify(obj));
    // res.send(req.body);
})
```

;

Every I run the program I get this error saying **"$.post is not a function"**

[image]

Comment: Based on the error, I assume you have an issue with the usage of jQuery. Do you load jQuery on your client page? try jQuery.post(....) instead or add jQuery library in your head.

Comment: I have added jQuery in my HTML, and I also tried using jQuery.post but it doesn't work

Comment: do you have other libraries loaded, have you ensured that the $.post is executed after jQuery is loaded? where do you execute $.post?

Comment: Are you using slim version of Jquery because Ajax is not part of slim version of jquery. You need to use minified version or uncompressed version of jquery.

Comment: I have also added libraries of bootstrap and mapbox, and my .post is executed after all the documents are load. inside $(document).function(){ // code  }

Answer (score 0):

The error sounds as if `$.post` is undefined. As such when you try to call it, JS errors as `undefined` is not a function.
If I open the console on a new-tab which doesn't have jquery imported the same error happens.

Inorder to use jquery you need to import the source. 
`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I have that script added in my HTML file,but the error is still there

Comment: are you able to access the jquery  and the post method by name rather than using the $ shortcut?

Comment: You clearly do not have jQuery imported correctly then.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answers you gave execute your `$.post` within

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // if you want to execute the post request after your DOM is ready
});
```

or

```
$(window).on("load", function() { 
  // when your page is fully loaded
});
```

Make sure you import the correct version of jQuery and that you don't have a conflicting library that binds on the global namespace you try to access jQueries `post()`. There might be no other reasons receiving that error message.

It just indicates that for `$` - the namespace you access jQuery - there doesn't exist the function you want to call.